# How to listen to Container Style Query change

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, responsive-design, media-queries

**Update 2** - Added a JS BIN: https://jsbin.com/wujizuyuqi/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="auto">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="DublinDev">

    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
        .parent {
            container-type: size;
        }

        @container (min-width: 500px) {
            .child {
                --size: "Large";
                background-color: olive;
            }
        }

        @container (max-width: 499px) {
            div .child {
                --size: "Small";
                background-color: cyan;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent" class="parent" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <div id="child" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="child"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
        const child = document.getElementById("child");

        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
            var size = window.getComputedStyle(child).getPropertyValue("--size")
            console.log(`Size: ${size}`);
        });

        resizeObserver.observe(child);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note, the whole point is to try getting rid of the resize observer and rely on an event, the same way as it's done for the regular media quires.

**Update 1** - I found a horrible workaround based on a custom property + ResizeObserver + window.getComputedStyle(), it might hold the water until a better solution arrives. It'd be still be great to know if the listener is coming.

Questions: How do I add a listener for a [container style query](https://css-tricks.com/early-days-of-container-style-queries/) change by analogy with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener)?

Comment: I think you should show your code

Comment: hmm, not sure if there's a clean way as of now, maybe you can dig up this github issue: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with `<iframe>`, since it has its own `window` interface.
What I did here:

1. create a "dummy" iframe
2. set the iframe size to the exact same size as the desired element
3. get a [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) using `.matchMedia()` method

It still needs a `ResizeObserver` (or a eventListener on `resize` event) to update the iframe size according to the element size, when it changes. And I don't think you can't get rid of any sort of observer until there's a native implementation like `element.matchMedia()`;
It's a bit of a hacky wacky solution, but you will get the same `MediaQueryList` as if you would run `window.matchMedia()` and you can work the same way with it. `.matches`, `.onchange`, `.addEventListener()` ..

Here's a JSFiddle because SO doesn't like iframes.
Also a note, in JSFiddle and JS Bin the eventListener doesn't work for the `MediaQueryList` coming from an iframe. So instad, I recommend to create a simple .html file and open it in your browser.
https://jsfiddle.net/sca5kbgh/55/

// HTML

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <div id="child" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

// CSS

```css
.parent {
  container-type: size;
}

@container (min-width: 500px) {
  .child {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}

@container (max-width: 499px) {
  div .child {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
}
```

// JS

```js
class ContainerMatchMedia {
    constructor (element, containerQueryString) {
    this.element = element;
    this.containerQueryString = containerQueryString;
    
    this.setupIframe();
    this.setupObserver();
    this.matchMedia();
  }
  
  setupIframe() {
    // Create an iframe, we use it to "fake" the element size annd apply matchmedia
    this.iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    this.iframe.id = 'container-match-media';

    // some stylings to hide the iframe
    this.iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.iframe.style.top = 0;
    this.iframe.style.left = 0;
    this.iframe.style.display = 'block';
    this.iframe.style.transform = 'translate(-100vw, -100vh)';
    
    // append the iframe to root element
    document.documentElement.appendChild(this.iframe);
  }
  
  setupObserver() {
    // we still need an observer to change the iframe size when the element changes
    this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      this.resizeIframeToElement(this.element, this.iframe);
    });

    this.resizeObserver.observe(this.element);  
  }
  
  resizeIframeToElement() {
    // get the elements dimensions
    var elementRect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // set the iframe dimensions to same as elements dimensions
    this.iframe.width = elementRect.width;
    this.iframe.height = elementRect.height;
    
    // here we see the MediaQueryList is changing when the iframe is being resized
    if (this.MediaQueryList) {
        console.log('Matches: ', this.MediaQueryList.matches);
    };
  }
  
  matchMedia() {
    /**
     * Now we have an iframe with same dimensions as the element
     * matchMedia will return a MediaQueryList
     */
    this.MediaQueryList = this.iframe.contentWindow.matchMedia(this.containerQueryString);
  }
}


const child = document.getElementById("child");
const CMM = new ContainerMatchMedia(child, '(min-width: 500px)');

// unfortunately, .onchange (or .addEventListener('change' ...)) doesn't work
CMM.MediaQueryList.onchange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: iframe sounds like a bit too high price to pay, specially considering the main pain - active resize event listeners are still there. agreed? I like the idea though.

Comment: PREV Comment continuation -  I can have dozens of components hosted within grids/flexes so if I understood correctly this would require each of them to be wrapped within an iframe?

Comment: Exactly, for each element you want to observe, there will be an additional iframe. This definitely shouldn't be done as soon as you have more than a handful of elements to keep track on.

Answer (score 0):

I offer 2 ways to add listeners for media queries:

1. With `.window.onresize`, define a variable to check if it is a state change.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
const child = document.getElementById("child");
let size = window.getComputedStyle(child).getPropertyValue("--size"), sizeNow;
window.onresize = () => {
  sizeNow = window.getComputedStyle(child).getPropertyValue("--size");
  if(size !== sizeNow) {
    console.log(sizeNow);
    size = sizeNow;
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  container-type: size;
}

@container (min-width: 500px) {
  .child {
    --size: "Large";
    background-color: olive;
  }
}

@container (max-width: 499px) {
  div .child {
    --size: "Small";
    background-color: cyan;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
<div id="child" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" class="child"></div>
```

2. With `MediaQueryList.onchange` as an alternative for `MediaQueryList.addListener` which is deprecated now.

```js
const child = document.getElementById("child");
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 499px)");
mediaQueryList.onchange = (e) => {
  let sizeNow = window.getComputedStyle(child).getPropertyValue("--size");
  if(e.matches) {
    // when width <= 499px
    console.log(1, sizeNow);
  } else {
    // when width > 499px
    console.log(2, sizeNow);
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  container-type: size;
}

@container (min-width: 500px) {
  .child {
    --size: "Large";
    background-color: olive;
  }
}

@container (max-width: 499px) {
  div .child {
    --size: "Small";
    background-color: cyan;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
<div id="child" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" class="child"></div>
```

Comment: what's the solution though? container can have its size totally different to the window's one. Also  containers can have their size changed without window being resized at all. Perhaps I just missed the point?

Comment: @user1514042 Have you tried to resize (horizontal) on the window? you will see the changes.

Comment: @Jordy your matchMedia is listening for changes on the window, not the element. It's only working as long as the element has the same width as the window. As soon as the element changes it's size without changing the window size, it's no longer correct.

Comment: @AlexBerger then replace `window` with any elements do you want.

Comment: matchMedia doesn't exist for other elements. It's only available for window